Playback / recording problems
The code I'm working on gives me some errors. This results in frame lost when recording.
The overview: A video is paused in the first frame. When the motion sensor is detected the video is playing a scary scene. After that it pauses again on the first frame.
At the same time when motion is detected the camera starts recording the reaction of the poeple watching the scary scene.
This is my code:
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from time import sleep
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import FfmpegOutput
import vlc
import datetime

# Creating Instance class object
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
player.set_fullscreen(True)
  
# Define Motion Sensor
pir = MotionSensor(4)

# Camera
camera = Picamera2()
video_config = camera.create_video_configuration()
camera.configure(video_config)
camera.rotation = 180
encoder = H264Encoder(bitrate=10000000)
output = FfmpegOutput('/home/wessie/Halloween/Recordings/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264'))

print("Sensor loading")
pir.wait_for_no_motion()
sleep(.1)
player.set_mrl("/home/wessie/Halloween/ScareMedia/FemaleScare.mp4")
player.play()
sleep(.1)

while True:
    try:
        print("Ready")
        pir.wait_for_motion()
        sleep(.1)
        print("Motion detected")
        sleep(.1)
        player.set_mrl("/home/wessie/Halloween/ScareMedia/FemaleScare.mp4")
        player.play()
        sleep(.1)
        camera.start_recording(encoder, output)
        sleep(12)
        camera.stop_recording()
        while player.get_state() in playing:
            sleep(.1)
            continue        
        print("Finished")
        sleep(.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        continue

After "Motion detected" the message is:
"Application provided invalid non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0:"
I've tried to cleanup this code, but everything I do results in other errors.
Is the code in the right order? The scary scene seems to work, but the recording is not 100%
